# Resources to simplify W3C standard implementation

Tags: parsing, svg, standards, dtd, w3c

At my company we’re looking to implement support for W3C standards, such as [SVG 1.1 (2nd edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html), in our app. I’ve been doing research on how people approach this problem.

There are various resources available at [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/), but the standard only appears to be available in HTML files. I would like to be able to parse a single document that gives me all of the concepts in the standard, which I can then generate objects from in a programming language of my choice.

Apart from simply parsing the HTML itself, it seems possible to parse the [document type definition file](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-flat.dtd), but this doesn’t include type information for attributes such as “color,” [whose constraints are described in EBNF in the html document](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#types-DataTypeColor).

What is the best approach to implementing a W3C standard, such as SVG 1.1 (2nd edition)?

Does it simply come down to manually tracking the different parts of the standard, as defined in the HTML?